# How to do stratified paired test?

Tags: r, paired-data

Suppose I have a data set such like:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(pre=rnorm(10,2,3),
post=rnorm(10,3,2),
type=rep(c("A","B"), each=5))
df
        pre    post type
1   0.31857  5.4482    A
2   1.30947  3.7196    A
3   6.67612  3.8015    A
4   2.21153  3.2214    A
5   2.38786  1.8883    A
6   7.14519  6.5738    B
7   3.38275  3.9957    B
8  -1.79518 -0.9332    B
9  -0.06056  4.4027    B
10  0.66301  2.0544    B
```

What I wanted to test is "given the type whether the means are different between pre and post"? Does somebody know how to do that test?

Comment: Are the pre/post values in pairs as in the data set? That is, is each row measured on a unique unit, or are there simply two units with 5 pre and 5 post measurements each?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Aaron. the pre/post is measure on one unit (paired) which means there are 10 units. But they are classified into to groups say black vs white.

Comment: Does "do" refer to "write code for" or does it mean "develop a statistical procedure for"?  Regardless, it sounds like a set of tests, rather than a single test.  Could you clarify these points?

Comment: I would find a proper methodology and it would be great to give an example using the demo data. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just performing a standard test, such as a Student t test, within each stratum?  In other words, could you tell us why you think the stratification presents any new challenge?

Comment: I had comducted paired t test within each type but wanted to do it with combined two types so that may be more powered.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?  After all, there's no hope of getting more power out of the combination unless there is some assumed relationship between the data in separate groups or some connection between the multiple hypotheses you are formulating--but you haven't yet said anything about such assumptions.